# how to install ndk in ubuntu , to delevelop android app

Tags: android-ndk

Installation
To install and configure the NDK, follow these steps:

Get and install the Android SDK.
Download the NDK, making sure to download the correct version for your development platform. You may place the unzipped directory anywhere on your local drive.

> Update your PATH environment variable with the location of the
>   directory that contains the NDK.

I cannot know "Update your PATH environment variable", 
how to update my path enviroment variable?

https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/setup.html

Answer (score 0):

In bash shell: `PATH=$PATH:<wherever you ndk is located>`

To make it permanent add this line to `~/.bashrc`